# EF group list doesn't group

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In a table I have a list of documents:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Slug {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string LanguageId {get;set;}
}
```

The table can have multiple documents with the same 'Slug', but with different 'LanguageId's.

I fetch the data like this:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetDocuments<T>(string languageId)
{
    var documents = await _dbContext.Documents
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.LanguageId == languageId)
        .ThenByDescending(x => x.LanguageId == "da")
        .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ProjectToType<T>()
        .ToListAsync();

    return documents;
}
```

The goal is to only get one document per 'Slug'. If it exists with the submitted 'languageId', that's what I want - if not, I want the one with LanguageId = "da".

It must be a GroupBy, but I can't get the desired result. My current approach is this:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetDocuments<T>(string languageId)
{
    var documents = await _dbContext.Documents
        .OrderByDescending(y => y.LanguageId == languageId)
        .ThenByDescending(y => y.LanguageId == "da")
        .ThenBy(y => y.Name)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Slug)
        .Select(x => x.First())
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ProjectToType<T>()
        .ToListAsync();

    return documents;
}
```

But that gives me all documents in the table.

Please help.

Comment: What does `ProjectToType` do?

Comment: ProjectToType<T> maps to the type T I provide. Basically just from the domain model to a dto with the same properties.

Comment: Please show code

Comment: I will in another question. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76987126/mapster-projecttotype-breaks-when-using-groupby-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetDocuments<T>(string languageId)
{
    var documents = await _dbContext.Documents
        .GroupBy(x => x.Slug)
        .Select(x => x
            .OrderByDescending(y => y.LanguageId == languageId)
            .ThenByDescending(y => y.LanguageId == "da")
            .ThenBy(y => y.Name)
            .First())
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ProjectToType<T>()
        .ToListAsync();

    return documents;
}
```

This way you form the groups way earlier. Then order each group by whatever you want to order it by. Then, select the first one.

Comment: That seems like a good approach, thanks. Sadly it gives me an error: `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary.`. It's probably not related to the GroupBy but to the mapper/projection. Right?

Comment: @Mads I am not sure that is due to the Linq but rather about the ProjectToType

Comment: I think so, but it's strange since it works perfectly without the GroupBy. It's the same properties with and without.

Comment: @Mads, remove the projectToType, try the code without it, if it works, try fixing the projection.

Comment: The query works without the ProjectToType

Comment: @Mads, if it does work as expected, I would say you should try to fix the projection error. If you are unable to do so you can ask another question on stackoverflow. Don't continue with this post, most people don't like 2 questions in the same post. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. You were first with a solution to the GroupBy, so I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code.  If null doesn't work try  DBNull.Value

```
var documents = await _dbContext.Documents
   .Select(x => new {doc = x, order = (x.LanguageId == null) ? 4 : (x.LanguageId == filter.PreferredLanguageId) ? 1 : (x.LanguageId == "da") ? 2 : 3})
   .OrderBy(x => x.order)
   .GroupBy(x => x.doc.Slug)
   .Select(x => x.First().doc)
   .AsNoTracking()
   .ProjectToType<T>()
   .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it but I still get the error `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary.`

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the linq statement.  Did you update properties in the class?  You need to do a migration to get the c# classes in sync with the database.  You database has a primary key EmptyProjectionMember which is not a key in the database.

Comment: The property may be null.  Try modified code.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't fix it. :(

Comment: Try DBNull.Value instead of null.

Comment: I don't think that's it. Code works without projection, so I'll have to look there. maybe ask a new question. Thanks anyway!